# oauth grant type для приложения с web brouser и мобильным клиентом, какой выбрать?

Tags: spring, oauth, oauth2

Сразу перейду к сути. 
К примеру есть множество микросервисов на Spring boot, auth-сервис, и надо настроить аутентификацию и авторизацию. Зайдя на https://auth0.com сталкиваешься с можнестовом различных grand types. И конечно же появился вопрос что мне выбрать для случая когда есть web-браузер клиент(обычное react или angular приложения, которое предназначено для работы с ПК) и mobile клиент/приложение. В доке ни плюсов, ни минусов нету, гугл выдает нечто двусмысленное, и поэтому я ничего конкретного не нашел.

Алгоритм аутентификации вижу следующим. Человек вводит пароль и логин, потом на auth-service аутентифицируется. Пароль для входа с какого либо девайса один и тот же. При смене пароля, аутентификация на других девайсах происходит заного(если конечно же пользователь на них уже был аутентифицирован). Жизнь подобия сессии бесконечна(до смены пароля либо возможного пронудительного выхода со всех устройств).

На мое скромное мнение без JdbcTokenStores тут не обойтись. Так же по доке понял что для микросервисов лучше всего использовать Client Credentials grant type, так ли это? А для пользователя возможно password или authorization code, что будут лучше в моем случае?

Буду рад послушать лучшие подходы и ваши мнения. Заранее благодарен!